# Template literal tag function issues when transpiling ES2015 to ES5 with Babel.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using Gulp and Babel to transpile ES2015 code to ES5. We are using template literals and a tag function to rip out any leading whitespace.

It looks like when transpiling that, the template literals are being added to the global scope with the same variable names. This is causing JavaScript templates to be overwritten in certain views.

**Gulp Task**

```
// Transpile ES2015 JS to ES5 JS
gulp.task('babel', function () {
    return gulp.src('precompiled/Views/**/*.js') // Gets all files ending with .js in precompiled/Views and children dirs
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(header('/* THIS IS A GENERATED FILE. MAKE CHANGES TO THE SOURCE FILE. CHANGES HERE ARE OVERWRITTEN. */\n\n'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Views')) // Outputs it in the Views folder
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ // Reloading with Browser Sync
            stream: true
        }));
});
```

**Example**

```
const singleLineString = function (strings) {
    const values = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    // Interweave the strings with the 
    // substitution vars first.
    let output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        output += strings[i] + values[i];
    }
    output += strings[values.length];

    // Split on newlines.
    const lines = output.split(/(?:\r\n|\n|\r)/);

    // Rip out the leading whitespace.
    return lines.map(function (line) {
        return line.replace(/^\s+/gm, '');
    }).join(' ').trim();
};

const firstFilesJSFunction = (name) => {
    return singleLineString `My name is ${name} and I am the best.`;
};

const secondJSFilesFunction = (candy) => {
    return singleLineString `I love ${candy} and ice cream.`;
};
```

My JavaScript uses a module design pattern so that scope does not become an issue. Although the example code is in a module, the transpiled, tagged object is still being placed on the global scope. Here is what the transpiled, tagged object may look like:

**First File**

```
var _templateObject = _taggedTemplateLiteral(["My name is ","and I am the best."])
```

**Second File**

```
var _templateObject = _taggedTemplateLiteral(["I love ","and ice cream."])
```

Since the variables are placed on the global scope the first variable will be replaced by the second variable.

Is there any way to scope these template objects? Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Image of the actual template objects created outside my module]

[image: Second module]

Thanks!

Comment: The top-level scope of a file is the module scope, not the global scope. The only way this would be an issue is if you are concatenating the files together, which you should never do. If the literals are in the same file, Babel will give them two different names.

Comment: Hello Logan thank you for the response. I am not concatenating the files. The Javascript files are included in the same file. Since babel is adding the variables outside the module at the top of the file I am seeing them placed on the global scope. I posted some pictures.

Comment: Babel assumes that files it outputs will be processed using a module bundler, or executed in a system supporting file-level modules. It puts it at the top-level of the file because it assumes the files have their own non-global scope.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to make this work? I am bundling in release mode but that does not seem to make a difference using BundleConfig. Overall this seems like a bad assumption. If I am defining a variable in my module with the result of my tagged template literal I would expect it to at least scope within the module.

Comment: The files Babel outputs are modules, so variables declared inside they are module-scoped. You would need to use a bundler that is aware of modules, like Browserify or Webpack. Unfortunately I have no experience with BundleConfig to know if there is a way to do it with that. It seems like it is just concatenating the files together, thus you end up with no module scope created for you.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that Babel makes no assumption whatsoever about modules or scope? AFAIK, it's "just" a transpiler that coverts JS in individual files into corresponding files with ES5 compliant code. Treating these files as modules and bundling them is up to some other tool.